# How to get tag properties from OSM in mapbox gl

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

```
map.on('click', 'building', function (e) {
    console.log(e.features);
});
```

I need to add some properties to the features object. Specifically the [website](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3Awebsite) and [description](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3Adescription)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the available properties by consulting the Mapbox Streets [layer reference](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-streets-v7/#layer-reference). The attributes you seek are not present, so you will have to use either some other source of vector tiles that contains them (possibly OpenMapTiles), or create your own.

Comment: I can generate vector tileset from a GeoJSON data set on overpass turbo. I've tried to query for descriptions and websites but have not been successful. Do you know what the query input would look like?

Comment: If you want to ask a question about Overpass, you should start a new question.